# How to solve: R CMD check report warning and error

Tags: r

I was using `R CMD check` to check my R package so that I can upload to CRAN, everything is fine but with 1 error and 1 warning for the manual. if I use `R CMD check --no-manual`,there will be no error and warning. Here, I want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks.

The error occurs when I run `R CMD check` in my local computer (centos system and R-4.0.2).

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR, 1 WARNING
```

Here, if you want to see the details of the error:

```
wget https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/pubmed.mineR_1.0.16.tar.gz
R CMD check pubmed.mineR_1.0.16.tar.gz
```

Comment: This error occurs on your local machine? Or you got a complaint from CRAN? Does `Rdlatex.log` or `00check.log` have any more details? What TeX installation do you have?

Comment: If you're using TeXlive with a Debian based Linux distribution, you can install the missing fonts by running `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended`.

Comment: You need some CentOS help with LaTeX. The error is from R trying to build the pdf manual of your package, yet your TeX installation seems incomplete.